# Replace Colors in Image with Transparency

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

How do I replace a color in an image which contains transparency with ImageMagick, but afterwards retain the transparency of the original image.

This is very useful for batch-changing of colors in icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

*Option 1*

A simpler option might be like this:

```
convert start.png -alpha deactivate -fill blue -opaque red -alpha activate result.png
```

which changes this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

*Option 2*

Another option, which uses an in-memory copy of the image, can also avoid the need to create 2 processes and write an intermediate file to disk:

```
convert start.png -write MPR:orig     \
   -alpha off -fill blue -opaque red  \
   MPR:orig -compose CopyOpacity -composite result.png
```

*Option 3*

Yet another method, that uses `clone` instead of MPR:

```
convert start.png                                   \
  \( +clone -alpha off -fill blue -opaque red \)    \
  +swap -compose CopyOpacity -composite result.png
```

**Original Answer**

If I create an image that contains transparency like this:

```
convert -size 400x400 xc:none -fill red -draw "rectangle 10,10 100,100" -fill blue -draw "rectangle 200,200 300,300" -bordercolor black -border 5 start.png
```

I'll get this (I am showing it overlaid on a checkerboard just to visualise the transparency):

[image]

If I now run this

```
convert start.png -fill yellow -opaque red result.png
```

I'll get this (again overlaid on a checkerboard):

[image]

Not sure why you need a more complicated, 2-stage process - or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Use an antialiased circle, and you will soon see what happens with the aliasing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't appreciate from your question that you would have varying degrees of transparency in icons - I incorrectly assumed they were a bit small for such things:-) I have added a couple of options that may save you (and other folk) some time if you have lots of icons to do - good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`convert file-in.png -alpha off -fill REPLACEMENT -opaque COLOR file-out.png`

then

`convert file-out.png file-in.png -compose CopyOpacity -composite PNG32:file-final.png`